# How to get local directory names into terminal window titles?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, bash, zsh

The title of my terminal window is:

*Terminal -- bash -- 130x39*

This is how I see them listed in Terminal->Window and it is very hard to know which one is which.

When I use multiple terminals, **the most important information** is the **local directory** in each of them.

Is there any way to have that local directory appear in the titles, so I could see easily which terminal is from where?

Answer (score 2):

Go to Preferences -> Profiles -> Window and check those things you would like to see in the terminal window title.

[image]

Comment: Sadly this option is not offered on 10.8

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev, I think this answer might be of help to you: https://superuser.com/questions/79972/set-the-title-of-the-terminal-window-to-the-current-directory